# CreateMutex vs System.Threading.Mutex (Win32 vs C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, mutex

I got a legacy code and I am trying to understand why the developer is using all the time the `CreateMutex` function from kernel32.dll and not `System.Threading.Mutex`.

I want to know if they are the same and if it is safe to change them from Windows API style to C# style.

This are the Mutexes I am talking about.

- [Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Maybe because the code is legacy?

Comment: Myabe :) What I want to know is, if there is a difference between them and if yes what is the difference. Also it will be nice to know if it will improve the code if I change to the .NET style(Performance, Stability and cet.)

Comment: Most likely no difference. I know that in recent years MS started to reduce complexity of .NET and making it closer to Win32.

Comment: In general they are the same, i.e. `System.Threading.Mutex` is essentially a managed wrapper for the respective Win32 API.

Comment: @KirillKobelev A "legacy" developer, maybe. But the `System.Threading.Mutex` class was there since .NET 1.0 (albeit maybe not with all features, haven't checked).

Comment: Legacy code could have transposed from even another langauge. On top, quite a significant percentage of developers dont know threading - add a bad advice here and there and he is not aware of System.Threading.Mutex. Can happen. But I would bet the code was transposed from another language.

Comment: I would wonder what the argument is for changing it if it passes all unit tests and has been a functioning application for a long enough time to be called "legacy". This will incur a large amount of regression testing. Don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: @TomTom This code wan't ported from another language. The developer did.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth I am going to port the entire code to .NET 4 so changes will have to be done. I want to remove as many(and hopefully all) calls to Win32 in order to see if I will be able to compile it under Mono.

Comment: ;) Stupid mistake on his part then - time to clean it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can find any docs on this topic. I think they are the same. I would recommend to change all calls to .NET. Even if you will discover problems (1% chance), it is better to fix them rather that keep direct calls to kernel32.